# Artificial food digestibility decrease

Tags: science-based, biology, food

Good day fellers. My question is -  how can one decrease the digestibility of consumed food?

I mean, if two characters consume the same amount of the same food, the one with such ability will get less calories and nutrients then the one without, but will poop more. I am writing a story, and one of the characters are to install an augment that does exactly what's written above. The augment model is probably some hormone or a enzyme inhibitor solution injected once or on a regular basis.

Amilaze inhibition only prevents carbohydrates from being absorbed, so that answer is partial, as there are also fats, proteins and micronutrients in food.

I tried to search the net, but the only related info is about negative digestibility caused by smoking and/or nicotine, and some articles about raw vs cooked.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? : https://www.nature.com/articles/srep11123

Comment: Thank you. Still, I consider that the article here does not answer my question completely, as scientists was measuring food digestibility on fats, and mice from experiment was also on high fat diet.

Comment: Go low Gi, your healthier choice.

Comment: Install an augment?  Get down to your gastroenterologist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjustable_gastric_band

Comment: A total gastrectomy :)

Answer (score 3):

Your modification allows the character to control their villi.

Villi (and microvilli) are [tiny, finger-like structures](https://study.com/academy/lesson/small-intestine-nutrient-absorption-and-role-in-digestions.html) in the small intestine that vastly increase the surface area and absorption ability of the tissue. If the modification were to simply allow your character to retract their villi and microvilli, their ability to absorb *any* nutrients is hugely decreased, as the small intestine is responsible for about 90% of your absorption.

**Edit:** Alternately, you could have your character control the porosity of their intestines. This way they could let tiny molecules like water pass through, but avoid larger proteins and fats. This could allow the character to very precisely affect which nutrients can be absorbed at any given time.

Comment: This is a good idea, I didn't think about direct control of a small intestine. The only negative consequence I see is probably chronic colitis, and that is not much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### I can think of two broad pathways that fit with your description: altering the structure of the food that is consumed, and altering the ability of a person's ability to digest things.

Changing the chemical structure of food can alter a body's ability to process it. This was the case for Olestra, a chemical used (briefly) by Lay's. Potato chips made with Olestra had synthetic fats which the human body couldn't absorb and metabolize, the idea being that the chips would taste great but not actually contribute fats that people metabolized. It also famously caused spontaneous anal leakage (hence the brief time on the market).

This would probably be difficult to achieve with the methods you outline in the question. Altering molecules is a very precise business, and this sort of alteration would probably require energy to make it happen. That would mean some kind of system which could analyze food as it's eaten, determine which alterations to make, get energy and reactive molecules suitable to the adjustment, and then actually chemically change the food. That's a lot.

Conversely, you could do something to alter the ability of a person to metabolize certain foods at all. Changing the composition of a person's GI flora population can have surprising effects on their ability to digest food. This is what fecal transplants are about. If someone's gut flora were expertly tweaked, and a given balance of bacteria maintained, you could do a lot to adjust what foods they could eat casually as well as what molecules are even present for their intestinal tract to absorb.

---

Other options exist which may accomplish the outcome you want but by other mechanisms. How well they fit your story I can't say.

An option like causing additional intestinal motility will cause food to spend less time in the GI tract at all, which will generally translate into fewer nutrients of any type being absorbed. Similar effects could be accomplished by shortening the small intestine.

On the flip side of that, you could (assuming some science fiction level technology) tweak a body's ability to produce certain enzymes or chemicals such as bile salts. That sort of thing won't usually be very general-purpose. The human body has lots of mechanisms which work for specific types of chemical ingested and work together to allow humans to eat a wide variety of foods. Using an option like this would probably be a combination of many different specific elements combined into a single medical product a consumer might purchase.

Comment: "tweak a body's ability to produce certain enzymes or chemicals such as bile salts",  
 "combination of many different specific elements combined into a single medical product" - yes, this is the general idea I had, and I hope to find a rough composition of such product. Perhaps the product could contain sodium for fats and amilaze inhibitor for carbs, but there is still a lot of nutrients left for consumption